# Validating JSON schemata with ajv with different schema versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajv

I want to validate a given [JSON](https://github.com/oasis-tcs/csaf/blob/master/csaf_2.0/examples/csaf/bsi-2022-0001.json) against [this](https://docs.oasis-open.org/csaf/csaf/v2.0/os/schemas/csaf_json_schema.json) schema.
I found out, that there are different subschemas referenced, namely:

- [CVSS V2](https://www.first.org/cvss/cvss-v2.0.json)
- [CVSS V3.0](https://www.first.org/cvss/cvss-v3.0.json)
- [CVSS V3.1](https://www.first.org/cvss/cvss-v3.1.json)

I recognized that in order to use the main schema which is from the kind `2020-12` I have to use the appropriate "compiler". In order to use the other schemata I tried to add them via `addSchema` in the hope this would "just work".

My code looks like the following:

```js
import csafSchema from '$lib/schema/csaf_json_schema.json';
import cvssv2 from '$lib/schema/cvss-v2.0.json';
import cvssv30 from '$lib/schema/cvss-v3.0.json';
import cvssv31 from '$lib/schema/cvss-v3.1.json';
import Ajv2020 from 'ajv/dist/2020';
import addFormats from 'ajv-formats';

const ajv = new Ajv2020({});
addFormats(ajv);

const validateJSONInput = (input) => {
    const validate = ajv.addSchema(cvssv2).addSchema(cvssv30).addSchema(cvssv31).compile(csafSchema);
    const valid = validate(input);
    return { isValid: valid, errors: validate.errors };
};

export { validateJSONInput };
```

The error I am getting is:

`no schema with key or ref "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"`

I assume `Ajv2020` is somehow not happy with mixed schemata versions because the other schemata are from the `draft-04` or the `draft-07` kind.

Could anybody give me a hint to manage such complex scenarios?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I just saw that [draft-04](https://ajv.js.org/guide/schema-language.html#draft-04) is no longer part of ajv. If that seems to be correct what would be a possible solution?